# Android: how autenticate to Firestore with signInWithCustomToken and listen/observe a document changes from a specific collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know how autenticate with signInWithCustomToken but I don't know how to listen/observe document changes in Android. I know how to do it in Angular so I will paste bellow just to exemplify.

If I turn off Firestore Rule Auth I can get the documents with

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
db.collection("transfer")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", exception)
    }
```

But I need to keep Auth in Firestore up and running like

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, update, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Well I know how to connect in Android using a CustomToken

```
      lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth// ...
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


        auth.signInWithCustomToken("eyJhbGc 
*** a valid customtoken *** Wi3KcvX4ILYN7kWySB4uuDtoNE_rIvXvD7VOpvCuLZ65d5lJHTBRhfAKJMiKyokQbWTZQ1GkQ")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    //updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //updateUI(null)
                }
            }
```

But I can't see a method in FirebaseAuth that allows me to set my collection and the listen/obeser/snapshot for changes taking advantage of Real Database feature of Firestore.

Just to exemplify what I am trying to do in Android/Kotlin, here is how I successfully reach it with Angular using snapshot and a customtoken

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public transfers: Observable<any[]>;

  transferCollectionRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, public db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.listenSingleTransferWithToken();
  }


  async listenSingleTransferWithToken() {
    await this.auth.signInWithCustomToken("ey *** valid customtoken *** daG1Q");
    this.transferCollectionRef = this.db.collection<any>('transfer', ref => ref.where("id", "==", "1"));
    this.transfers = this.transferCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data();
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });

  }
```

*** edited

[image: Signed in with cutomtoken]

*** Current Solution found. Since it is my first project in Firestore/Android any recommendation will be highly appreciated. BTW, this is working:

```
package com.example.demo
//https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#kotlin+ktx

// Tutorial to CustomToken
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#kotlin+ktx

//Tutorial to Snatshot Listeners and its queries
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlin+ktx

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val TAG = "MainActivity"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        auth.signInWithCustomToken("eyJ **** uXa-CSuHUrg")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "*** signInWithCustomToken:success")
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }

        //val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("transfer")
            .whereEqualTo("id", "1")
            .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                val transfer = ArrayList<String>()
                for (doc in value!!) {
                    doc.getString("status")?.let {
                        transfer.add(it)
                    }
                }
//                for (document in value) {
//                    Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
//                }
                Log.d(TAG, "*** transfer: $transfer")
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: For the authentication and custom token, you may look at the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#kotlin+ktx_1) on Android using Kotlin. This other [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) will show you how to implement a listener for any realtime updates using Kotlin in Cloud Firestore. Hope it helps.

Comment: @sllopis, thanks but I am still stuck. If you note my question it show that I know how to sign in with CustomToken (auth.signInWithCustomToken().addOnCompleteListener) but then I can add Snapshot listener. I need some method  like snapshotChanges after I sign in with CustomToken and none of the two links you suggested realy shows how

Comment: @sllopis I just added a print screen from my Android Studio with evidence that the CustomToken is valied and it is signed in. But how listen/observe/snapshotChanges the collection document?

Comment: @sllopis thank you so much. After numerous tentatives I got it working. May I ask you to just run your eyes and see if I am doing some weird thing? Firstly, I use FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(my cutsomtoken).addOnCompleteListener and secondlly FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("transfer")
            .whereEqualTo("id", "1")
            .addSnapshotListener. With Firestore Customtoken best practice in mind, do you see any strange thing on that? (See full code above please). Maybe you can set your first comment as answer so I can pick it

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that you got it working. The `signInWithCustomToken` method and `addSnapshotListener` observable both look fine. Btw, I posted your current working code as an answer, so other users can benefit from this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Current working solution**:

```
package com.example.demo
//https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#kotlin+ktx

// Tutorial to CustomToken
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#kotlin+ktx

//Tutorial to Snatshot Listeners and its queries
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlin+ktx

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val TAG = "MainActivity"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        auth.signInWithCustomToken("eyJ **** uXa-CSuHUrg")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "*** signInWithCustomToken:success")
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }

        //val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("transfer")
            .whereEqualTo("id", "1")
            .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                val transfer = ArrayList<String>()
                for (doc in value!!) {
                    doc.getString("status")?.let {
                        transfer.add(it)
                    }
                }
//                for (document in value) {
//                    Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
//                }
                Log.d(TAG, "*** transfer: $transfer")
            }
    }

}
```